# How to change the theme of application if the system theme has been change in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, colors, background, themes

How to change the theme of application if the system theme has been change in Windows Phone 7 if application in Runing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a bug when changing themes when app is deactivated and reactivated in Windows Phone Mango](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324476/is-there-a-bug-when-changing-themes-when-app-is-deactivated-and-reactivated-in-wi)

Comment: but the problem still not solved ...

Comment: That's correct. The bug was not fixed in the RTM of Mango so there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

The system theme applies throughout all apps. So if system them changes and you have used one of the system defined colors/ fonts, etc in your app, the app will automatically start using the new theme colors/ fonts.

So for eg: in your app, if you have:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="My App Title" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Page Title" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
```

here "StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle" specifies that you are using this system defined style. Now when user changes their system theme, this will automatically change colors in your app. also.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769545(v=vs.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769545%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: These actions are relevant, if the application is started again ... performed Application_Launching ..
And if the application is running, and I press the Windows key and change the system theme, then hold the button Back, and choose your application, ie performed Application_Activated, then subject to the application is an old topic ... even though the phone is another ...