# How to detect when the theme is changed in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

My app is fully theme aware. When my app is deactivated and user changes theme from dark to light (let's say) and returns to my application, the theme is not refreshed. Even though the phone theme is light my app still remains dark.

I did some tryings but they report the same values.
I declared a variable called isDarkThemeSelected, saved the value in deactivated event, changed the theme, and entered back into my application. But when the activated event is raised the variable value still remain the same.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Are you backing up your data when navigating out of the application, if so.....is it backing up the theme, that could cause an issue like that.

Answer (score 6):

Add this code to your main page constructor:

```
var v = (Visibility)Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"];
Debug.WriteLine("Using " + (v == Visibility.Visible ? "light" : "dark") + " theme");
```

(It detects the current theme and writes to the Output window which one it is.)

Then start the app, look at the Output in Visual Studio, close the app, change the theme, start the app and look again. If it says different things the first time and the second time then your app isn't as theme-aware as you think.

**Edit:** It seems like this doesn't always work due to a [Mango bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324476/is-there-a-bug-when-changing-themes-when-app-is-deactivated-and-reactivated-in-w). The theme remains the same when you *navigate back* to the app after changing the theme. It is only when the user *restarts* the app from the app list that the new theme is applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have tried the same code, Its gives proper theme but When my app is deactivated and user changes the theme and activates my application, that time this gives wrong theme information.

Comment: Then you're running this code in a wrong place. You should notice that the theme doesn't change instantly, but instead re-actives to the theme at the previous launch, and then changes to the new theme after rendering the UI at least once. Regardless, it shouldn't be necessary to check for the theme, unless you designed your application very poorly.

Comment: @Jorgensen, In Mango devices I observed a bug that the resource variable value doesn't changes. But same solution works in the Wp7.0. So I wanted check is this really bug or my faulty code.