# change Background same time like people Hub

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I working with my app. I saw people hub change color when i change theme in settings. And it worked too with my ApplicationBar. But i don't know how to do like this with my grid app ( at the default mode, background can't change until i quit and open this app again.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a known issue relating to this particular behaviour :-

[Is there a bug when changing themes when app is deactivated and reactivated in Windows Phone Mango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324476/is-there-a-bug-when-changing-themes-when-app-is-deactivated-and-reactivated-in-w)

Comment: I saw it. but it can change with Application Bar. So I hope we can do it with background :). thanks !